# Apache RewriteRule issue

Tags: apache

I am using below rules :

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/carddav
   RewriteRule (.*) /servlet/cdav/ [L,R]
```

These are working fine.If any request is coming with `/.well-known/carddav` that is redirect / rewrite to `/servlet/cdav`.

But if i use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /.well-known/carddav/ /servlet/cdav/ [L,R]
```

With no `RewriteCond` condition.These rules are not working.

Any clue ?

Comment: hm. none of the path are virtual/shortcut but physical directories, right? Did you try adding RewriteBase to www root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ii was a issue of `/` after /.well-known/carddav